# Python selenium's is_element_present is giving "wrong" answer

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to scrape a page where, if data exists, the page has the following "Table view" element:

```
<div class="floatRight">
   <a id="MainContent_TabContainerUsageAndCost_TabPanelGasUsage_GasUsageView_UCGasUsage_lnkTableView2" title="Table View" href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$ctl00$MainContent$TabContainerUsageAndCost$TabPanelGasUsage$GasUsageView$UCGasUsage$lnkTableView2&#39;,&#39;&#39;)" style="color:NoColor;">Table View</a>

</div>
```

Else, the page has the following error message.

```
<div class="error display">
                <span id="MainContent_TabContainerUsageAndCost_TabPanelElectricityUsage_ElectricityUsageView_UCElectricityUsage_lblMesg" style="font-weight:bold;">The account selected has no usage and costs data currently to be displayed.</span>

</div>
```

In selenium I am trying to check for the above two conditions before beginning to scrape data. I tried the following:

```
if self.selenium.is_element_present('link=Table view'):
   self.selenium.click('link=Table view')
else:
   return []  # data not found
```

But, the "if" statement is always returning "true" so that the "click" is being called even though the page did not have the "Table view" link/element.

So then, I rewrote the code to check for the error message instead, as follows:

```
if self.selenium.is_element_present('MainContent_TabContainerUsageAndCost_TabPanelElectricityUsage_ElectricityUsageView_UCElectricityUsage_lblMesg'):
    return []  # data not found
else:
    self.selenium.click('link=Table view')
```

And now, the "if" statement is always returning false, so that the "click" is being called when it should not!

Clearly, I am not using is_element_present correctly. Please advise.

Answer (score 1):

In Se-RC, your script can send click events to elements even if they are not visible to the user -- they just need to be in the DOM. In Se-WebDriver an element must also be visible to the user. Without seeing he full HTML of the page you are scraping it is impossible to further diagnose.

Comment: Thank you -- this was very helpful. And I was able to solve the problem. Thank you!